# Globally monitor unfulfilled promises to show indicator

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I want to show "loading" indicator if there is any unfulfilled promise. And this should be global, i.e. I don't want to show/hide this indicator manually in every place.

The reason why is that Ember's "loading" route is very limited. It doesn't work with back button and in components. And I want to show this "loading" indicator always if there is a single active promise. Doesn't matter what it's doing, I don't care, just want to show the indicator.

Is there a way to do this? Or is this bad idea?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, usability and programmatic wise.

Answer (score 1):

For global share state within the application, you can use `service` to do that.

Make your components to observe the state of promise declared inside the `service`.

You can read more about service at,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/

Do NOT overuse it since it is global state which can make your application too complicate to manage.

Comment: but how to monitor all promises in the app? sure I can use service as a wrapper for promise and use it, but for example how to teach ember-data to use this wrapper?

Comment: adapter? I have done this before but adapter is where the request is fired

Comment: adapter - maybe, I'll dig into it, thanks. Actually what I'm looking for is tha analog of Ruby's ObjectSpace module to get all allocated promises in the app without knowing where exactly they've been created. Or monkey-patch promise